# Can I create AWS API Gateway and S3 bucket only public to VPN

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway

I have a single page application on S3 and its REST API on AWS API Gateway.

How can I restrict access to the SPA only with a VPN.

I'd like to let the login page not public to the Internet.

Comment: If you are using s3 website endpoint, then it must be public. You could maybe limit it to a public IP of your NAT gateway. AWS VPN does not support proxy to NAT, so you would have to setup custom solution to enable your VPN traffic to go to the nat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exist a way to allow or block traffic from specific ip address (SourceIp) or from vpc endpoint (SourceVpc) in aws s3 bucket policy. We can specify such conditions to restrict access to s3 bucket.

For more details please visit this [link](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/block-s3-traffic-vpc-ip/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It was a great help!